# Sticky window footer using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I saw a [solution](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/jquery-sticky-footer/) (with a screen rewrite fix in the comments [from Luco](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/jquery-sticky-footer/#comment-100661)) that does what I want.. but anyway, here is the fixed (and tested) code:

```
// Window load event used just in case window height is dependent upon images
$(window).bind("load", function() { 

    var footerHeight = 0,
        footerTop = 0,
        $footer = $("#footer");

    positionFooter();

    function positionFooter() {

        footerHeight = $footer.outerHeight(); // include padding/margins
        footerTop = ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() - footerHeight) + "px";

        if (($(document.body).height() + footerHeight) < $(window).height()) {
            $footer.css({
                position: "absolute",
                top: $footer.offset().top // include padding/margins
            }).stop().
                animate({
                top: footerTop
            },-1);
        } else {
            $footer.css({
                position: "static"
            });
        }
    }

    $(window)
     .scroll(positionFooter)
     .resize(positionFooter)

});
```

.. which works when I use jquery version 1.3.2. However, I want to use version 1.12.4.. but when I do, it breaks. (it's also using bootstrap, just FYI) Why?

Comment: Check the console for errors.

Comment: Not sure, but why can you not use jQuery version 1.3.2? Or better yet, jQuery version 2.x or 3.x?

Comment: @Goose I tried v2.2.4, same results.. it doesn't work.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I checked the console.. no errors..

Comment: @Malachi So it works on jQuery 1.3.2 but not 1.12.4 or 2.2.4? Is that accurate?

Comment: .. I found the answer.. I made a test page in codepen that was pretty similar and it worked there. So I had to go line by line to find out what exactly was different. The difference was.. I was missing "<!DOCTYPE html>" at the very top of my page. Apparently jquery tripped over that somehow. Not sure why, but it did.. *facepalm*

Answer (score 2):

This can be done purely on CSS with Flexbox. You can use any container instead of `body`. I am using `body` just for example purposes.

If you want it to be really sticky and stick on the bottom of your window just add:

```
footer
{
    position: sticky;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```css
body
{
  /* Set minimum height to 100% of our viewport height */
  min-height: 100vh;
  /* Enable flexbox for the container */
  display: flex;
  /* Set flexbox layout to column */
  flex-direction: column;
  /* Center items on the flex axis */
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
}

footer
{
  /* Add infinite margin from top */
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<main>
Hey it's main content here
</main>
<footer>
Look I'm sticky!
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

It does work.. make sure to make the page correct in terms of html tags, like have "" at the top of the page...